# Select rows by multiples conditions at columns

Tags: r, filter, dplyr

I'm trying to get a value from different columns but at the same position in the string. The column value looks like:

```
"0/1:15,0,52:3:13"
"1/0:15,0,52:3:13"
"0/0:15,0,52:3:13"
"1/1:15,0,52:3:13"
```

And i want to filter by `0/1` and get all the rows that match with that condition by a `data.frame`. For that I can use:

```
df1 <- dplyr::filter(df, grepl("0/1", nameofthecolumn))
```

And it works but when I try to filter by **2 conditions** like `0/1` and `1/1` I try the following  line and it does not work. That line returns an empty `data.frame` `0 obs. of X variables`:

```
df1 <- dplyr::filter(df, grepl(paste("0/1", "1/1"), paste("namesofthecolumn1", "nameofthecolumn2"))
```

Then I need to fix that function and make different conditions for different columns, and if a row (same row for X columns) contains `0/1`, the other column `1/1` and the other "0/0", count all the 1s so i get the value : `3`.

Then I'm asking two questions:

1 - How can I fix my line to filter by a list of conditions and a list of columns?

2 - How can I sum/count all the 1s from a row by a list of columns?

Any help would be appreciated.

Edit:

Example of data.frame to work:

```
column1 <- c("0/1:15,0,52:3:13", "1/1:152,144,0,132,107,129:49:99", "0/1:26,0,7:54:10", "0/0:0,12,115:4:14", "1/1:219,57,0:19:99", "0/0:0,21,255:96:21")
column2 <- c("1/1:15,0,52:3:13", "1/1:152,144,0,132,107,129:49:99", "0/1:26,0,7:54:10", "0/1:0,12,115:4:14", "0/0:219,57,0:19:99", "0/0:0,21,255:96:21")
chrom <- c("chr0", "chr0", "chr1", "chr1", "chr2", "chr2")
df <- data.frame(chrom, column1, column2)
```

I want to filter for example by 0/1 and 1/1 so i get all the rows that at least have 0/1 or 1/1:

```
chrom   column1             colum2
chr 0   0/1:15,0,52:3:13    1/1:15,0,52:3:13
chr 0   1/1:152,144,0,132,107,129:49:99    1/1:152,144,0,132,107,129:49:99
chr 1   0/1:26,0,7:54:10    0/1:26,0,7:54:10
chr 1   0/0:0,12,115:4:14   0/1:0,12,115:4:14
chr 2   1/1:219,57,0:19:99  0/0:219,57,0:19:99
```

I get all rows except the last one because the last one does not contain 0/1 or 1/1.

Comment: can't you simply remove everything before the `:` in the substring before the first `,` ?
Or you could build a pipe in which you extract the substring before the `:`, and create kind of a "primary key" column used to filter or whatever else

Comment: Remove elements it's not a choice because i need the complete string for each column in each row.

Comment: the idea is to have a data.frame in which each row is a vector like `c("0/1", "0/1:15,0,52:3:13")`. So you are not removing anything, you just use `0/1` for do the operation you need. However, I cannot write an answer because I have not really understood you question since you are not sharing input data nor the expected output.

Comment: It's just about filter and get all rows that have the X column value like "0/1" or c("0/1", "1/1") of the column value `"0/1:15,0,52:3:13"` and get a data.frame with all those filtered rows.

Comment: I want to get a data.frame, look at my last words of my last answer

Comment: Does my solution answer your problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You require a mix of regex and concatenation of your columns as such

```
df1 <-  dplyr::filter(df, grepl(paste(c("0/1", "1/0"), collapse = "|"), 
                                paste(column1, column2, sep = "_")))
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the following input data:

```
input <- c("0/1:15,0,52:3:13", "1/0:15,0,52:3:13", "0/0:15,0,52:3:13", "1/1:15,0,52:3:13")
```

Let's obtain a vector containing only the element we will use for filtering:

```
key <- unlist(lapply(strsplit(unlist(lapply(strsplit(input, ","), "[[", 1)), ":"), "[[", 1))
```

At this point we create a data.frame with two columns: the value used for filtering and the input data we want to filter. Note that the input data is the original vector with the entire string.

```
df <- data.frame(key = key, input = input,
                 stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
```

Finally, we can use the column `key` to filter the input data with the condition you prefer. The output is a data.frame with only one column containing the input data filtered:

```
result <- data.frame(df[df$key %in% c("0/1", "1/1"), -1])

print(result)

             value
1 0/1:15,0,52:3:13
2 1/1:15,0,52:3:13
```

Comment: Sorry if i was not that clear, my data to filter will be a list of columns that have values like: `"0/1:15,0,52:3:13"` and the data.frame i want to get is the `df` rows that match with the other columns that have "0/1" and "1/1".

Comment: I suggest you to provide a reproducible example, a clear explanation of the problem and a concise question to answer otherwise it is very difficult someone can help you